# Using V-for in checkboxes in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am able to list values and save them to the database without any problem using axios>>vue JS>>spring boot. My problem I want to trigger my save method only when checkbox is selected or true in Vue JS. In my case am using v-on:change in my checkbox but the method get invoked every time i click the checkbox. is there a way I can invoke my save method only when the checkbox is selected(true). 
my data from the database get displayed as shown

[image]

here is my code:

```
      <thead>
          <tr>  <th>ID</th>
                <th>Subject Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr  v-for="item in subjectData">
                 <td>{{item.id}}</td> <td>{{item.subjectName}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" v-on:change.prevent="saveMarks(item)" /></td>
                         </tr>  
    </tbody>
           </table>
   </div>
   <script>
var subjectStudentsVM=new Vue({
el:"#subjectStudentsSelection",
data:function(){    
    return {
        id: '',
        studid:'',
        subjectData:Array(),
    }
},

created:function (){
this.getAllSubjects();
},
methods:{
        saveMarks: function(item) {
        var self=this;
        axios({
          method:"POST",
          url:"/Student/"+this.studid+"/"+item.id, 
         // url:"/Student/2/2", 
              headers: {
                  'content-type': 'application/json',
              },
              data:{
                    }
            })
    },
    getAllSubjects:function(){
        var self=this;
          axios.get("/Subject/list/").then(function (response) {
                this.subjectData = response.data;
          }.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error while fetching subject data: ' + error)
          })
    },
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check inside your function `saveMarks` what the state of the checkbox is and *only* then save.
Like so:

```
 saveMarks: function(item,event) {
            var self=this;
            if (event.target.checked === true){
            axios({
              method:"POST",
              url:"/Student/"+this.studid+"/"+item.id, 
             // url:"/Student/2/2", 
                  headers: {
                      'content-type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  data:{

                        }

                })

                console.log("record  saved");
               }else{

                    console.log("record not saved");
                    //return

                }
```

Comment: I adjusted to this but I get in my console record not saved. Where may be the problem. This is the code:saveMarks: function(item,event) {
   var self=this;
   if (event.checked === true){
         axios({
        method:"POST",
        url:"/Student/"+this.studid+"/"+item.id, 
       // url:"/Student/2/2", 
         headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
         },
         data:{
                    
         }
         
         })}else{
          
          console.log("record not saved"+event);
          //return
          
         }

Comment: see my edit, it needs to be in a v-mode, the event does seem to contain the value.